# oracle specific SQL query with AND and OR compound statements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have the following query..

```
select * 
  from  TABLE
 where (to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') + (AUDITTIMESTAMP/60/60/24/1000)) < to_date('2012-11-18 10:06', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
   AND (to_date('1970-01-01 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss') + (AUDITTIMESTAMP/60/60/24/1000)) > to_date('2012-11-17 22:06', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss')  
   AND (
     --(COLUMNA like '%aaa%' AND COLUMNAA like '%aaaaaaaaaaaaa%')
       (COLUMNB like '%bbb%' AND COLUMNBB like '%bbbbbbbbbbbbbb%')
     --or(COLUMNC like '%ccc%' AND COLUMNCC like '%ccccccccccccccc%') 
     --or (COLUMND like '%ddd%' AND COLUMNDD like '%ddddddddd%')
     )
 order by COLUMN1_PK
```

For each condition in compound OR statement within brackets, there are records in the database.

But when I have a single statement inside this compound block, there are NO records returning back.

How can I change this to fix this problem?

Comment: are you saying that in its posted form, records are being returned but if you uncomment the following `or(COLUMNC like '%bbb%' AND...` line, you get no records? I would not expect that.

Comment: no ..the problem is that if I uncomment 
(COLUMNA like '%aaa%' AND COLUMNAA like '%aaaaaaaaaaaaa%')

and add or to the next line, the results are returned,

and all the results are evaluated for 1st column only..ignores 
AND COLUMNBB like '%bbbbbbbbbbbbbb%' part...

Comment: Your last comment (partly) contradicts what you said in your question, and so just muddies the water.  Please post some representative data and show us the expected and actual outputs.

Comment: as I have realized, the cause of this issue is when we encountered an OR it will ignore the statement before the entire block and execute the clause after OR, therefore ignores all the part that does the date filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer, just some debugging assistance with the luxury of code formatting. Perhaps you could move your WHERE clause into the columns and leave the data unfiltered to see exactly what is going on. This often helps you see something that may not be obvious. You should see in your resultset that a 1 appearing in C1 OR C2 will result in a 1 appearing in C3. Try that and comment back.

```
select 
  CASE 
    WHEN COLUMNA like '%aaa%' AND COLUMNAA like '%aaaaaaaaaaaaa%'  
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END C1,
  CASE 
    WHEN COLUMNB like '%bbb%' AND COLUMNBB like '%bbbbbbbbbbbbbb%' 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END C2,
  CASE WHEN (
    (COLUMNA like '%aaa%' AND COLUMNAA like '%aaaaaaaaaaaaa%') OR
    (COLUMNB like '%bbb%' AND COLUMNBB like '%bbbbbbbbbbbbbb%') 
    THEN 1 ESLE 0 END C3
from  TABLE
where date '1970-01-01' + AUDITTIMESTAMP/60/60/24/1000
  between timestamp '2012-11-17 22:06:01' and timestamp '2012-11-18 10:05:59'
order by COLUMN1_PK
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you say is happening really were happening it would be most surprising, and worrying, because it would indicate something dramtaically wrong with Oracle.  Fortunately it is not the case: as [this SQL Fiddle demonstrates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2239b/1) the uncompounded condition *does* match on both columns, not just the first one.

The most likely explanation for what you are seeing is a problem with your data, or rather your understanding of the data.  You just don't have any records which match on COLUMNB and COLUMNBB within the specified timeframe.

---

If you disagree with this assessment please post *just enough* representative data to act as a test case.